# Why does Google return more results if I add an exclusion clause?

Tags: search, google-search

I *thought* I understood the exclusion operator (-) in Google, but I'm getting unexpected results.

Example:
If I search for 'iphone' (without single quotes), Google says there are 3,880,000,000 results
If I search for 'iphone -"something_arbitrary"' (without single quotes),  Google says there are 6,090,000,000 results, which is almost twice as much as the search WITHOUT the exclusion.

Comment: Google result counts are very imprecise.  Look at a later result page.

Comment: I can understand some rounding for optimization purposes...but adding an exclusion clause caused over 2 billion additional results to show up.  That's more than a rounding error...I hope. :-\

Comment: The result number has at best a magnitude relevance.